# asserting and verifying date format DD-MM-YYYY in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, date, xpath, automation

[image]I am trying to automate using python selenium and the task is to

(1). verify if date is displayed

(2). if displayed - print that date

(3). Finally assert and verify whether the date displayed is the right format as expected (i.e) DD-MM-YYYY.

sometimes we find that once the form is submitted, the field label date added shows format as MM-DD-YYYY but as per requirement it should be DD-MM-YYYY, so we decided to automate this test, so that once submitted we want to check above 3 points and I have written the following code where I am able to solve point 1 and 2, but struggling with point 3

'step 1': I have identified the element' xpath and stored it in variable called 'element'

'step 2': I have used a 'If statement' with length 'len' function - as a mode of verifying if date is present / displayed

'step 3': if displayed print it the date successfully

'step 4': Finally , how to do i verify if the date displayed is in the the format as we expected

### The following code I have written/screenshot attached for reference

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="incDetailTab"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[7]/strong')
    assert driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="incDetailTab"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[7]/strong')

    if (len(element.text) == 0):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")

    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Presume that you have the date string using `element.text`.However you can try this below function to check the date format.

```
import datetime

def checkvaliddateformat(datestr):

  day,month,year = datestr.split('-')
  isValidDate = True
  try :
       datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
  except ValueError :
       isValidDate = False

  if(isValidDate) :
      print ("date is valid format(DD-MM-YYY) : "+datestr)
  else :
      print ("date is not valid format(DD-MM-YYY) : " +datestr)

checkvaliddateformat('30-12-2020')
checkvaliddateformat('12-30-2020')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

XPath solution :

```
substring(//*@id="incDetailTab"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[7]/strong/@style,1,2)<=31 and substring(//*@id="incDetailTab"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[7]/strong/@style,4,2)<=12 and string-length(substring(//*@id="incDetailTab"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[7]/strong/@style,7,4))=4
```

Returns true if date is correctly displayed. Check the range of days, months and years.
Not a perfect solution since this expression assume "11.10.2018" is displayed in correct format whereas it might be not (MM.DD.YYYY).